# mongo c driver ./configure; no such file or directory

Tags: bash, makefile, configure, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I am trying to install mongo-c-driver there follow by http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.14.0/installing.html. Snce I don't have the root permission, I ran the following:

```
$ wget https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/releases/download/1.17.0-rc0/mongo-c-driver-1.17.0-rc0.tar.gz
$ tar xzf mongo-c-driver-1.17.0-rc0.tar.gz
$ cd mongo-c-driver-1.17.0-rc0
$ mkdir cmake-build
$ cd cmake-build
$ cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF ..
$ make 
$ make install
```

Where this error was shown:

```
-- Install configuration: "RelWithDebInfo"
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:46 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/share/mongo-c-driver.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.
```

So I tried to execute this:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/mypath/mongo-c-driver
```

which camp up with the error:

```
./configure: No such file or directory
```

The solutions that I found telling me to use `./autofen.sh` or  `./buildconf`  or  `autoreconf -i` which yield errors as well ...

Comment: Try setting DESTDIR in your make invocations: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/DESTDIR.html#envvar:DESTDIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the cmake file generated, you can see this block:

```
$ head cmake_install.cmake
# Install script for directory: /home/mhristof/mongo-c-driver-1.17.0-rc0

# Set the install prefix
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/home/mhristof/mongo-c-driver-1.17.0-rc0/cmakestuff/foobar")
endif()
string(REGEX REPLACE "/$" "" CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
```

So you need to define `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when you build your cmake files.

for example, instead of

```
cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF ..
```

you need

```
cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/foobar ..
```

Comment: But in this way, when I complie the hello_mongo.c http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/1.14.0/tutorial.html to test by `gcc -o hello_mongoc hello_mongoc.c \
    -I/mypath/nclude/libbson-1.0 -I/mypath/include/libmongoc-1.0 \
    -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0` , it gave me the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmongoc-1.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbson-1.0` it looks like I should alter the path to system variables or something?

Comment: I think so. I would play around with the `-I` args and try to point it to my custom folder. I havent done c for over 10 years so im not sure about what needs changing. If you cant find the answer, feel free to post another question with examples (ie whats your c code looking like) and im sure someone will be able to guide you.

Comment: I add the link path to the command, and add the link path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH that works, thanks^^